# Create FactoryGirl factory from real data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my web application user uploads files with data, but files not stored, and all I have is about 1000 records in few tables related to this file.

Recently I've found an error with application, I've fixed it and I want to write few tests to prevent this error from appear in future.

So, my question is - is there any way to save this data to use it in factory or I should write factory just to reproduce this error on smaller amount of data?